# Downsample vs custom latency register

Tags: xilinx, matlab

Is there a difference between `downsample` block (eg. in `matlab`) versus a `register` with custom latency or delay block.

As far as I understood, `downsample` block just ignores the intermediate samples. If I had a register with similar delay, it would ignore the intermediate samples as well, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a register with 2 cycles delay will output all the inputs (but delayed) - a downsampler only outputs some of the inputs:

```
Tick        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Input       A B C D E ...
Delay2      ? ? A B C D E ...
Downsample2 ? ? A A C C E E
```